# Filtering numpy using array operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations, python-itertools

I am using python and trying to filter a 2d array to only include arrays with a certain sum and that don't include the element 0.

Other tutorials seem to show how to filter arrays to get certain elements that meet a condition using numpy.where for instance, but I am trying to only get certain arrays that meet a condition without using loops of course, but rather a numpy method.

Like this operation, but with arrays and numpy:

```
import itertools

list_o_tuples = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x)==10 and 0 not in x, 
                    itertools.combinations(range(10),3)))
#returns [(1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
test = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(10),3)))
mask = (test.sum(axis=1) == 10) & (test.all(axis=1))
test[mask]
```

For extra safety / readability, you may want to use `(test != 0).all(axis=1)` instead of `test.all(axis=1)`.

Comment: Looks good to me: https://ideone.com/1eG5F2. Feel free to add the link to your answer.

Comment: Thank you, do you mind explaining what the second line is doing? I know np.sum(axis=1) but not the case of a = np.array((0,1,2)) a.sum(axis=1) or a.all.

Comment: Lastly, is there a way to do sum and another operation, like divide all elements by 2 and then add them to get 5 in this instance?

Comment: 2nd line creates a boolean mask with exactly the logic you are after: will give `True` if the row sums to `10` and all element evaluate to `True` (i.e are non 0 in your case, see second version for safety and clarity). You can of course use any more complex formula... The last line then selects the row where the mask is `True`.